# How can I push more products into my Cart in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to push more items into my cart but it ended up show only 1 item when I click into cart.

Here is my reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    products: [],
    loading: false,
    basketNumbers: 0,
    cartCost: 0,
    numbers: 0,
    inCart: false
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOADING:
            return {
                ...state,
                products: [],
                loading: true,
                err: ''
            };

        case SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                products: action.payload,
                loading: false,
                err: ''
            };
        case ADD_PRODUCT_BASKET:
            let numbers = (state.numbers += 1);
            let inCart = (state.inCart = true);
            
            return {
                ...state,
                basketNumbers: state.basketNumbers + 1,
                cartCost: state.cartCost + action.payload.price,
                product: action.payload,
                numbers: numbers,
                inCart: inCart
            };
}
```

and here is my cart page:

```
let productsInCart = [];

if (basketProps.inCart) {
    productsInCart.push(basketProps.product);
}
console.log(basketProps);
console.log(productsInCart);
```

I tried to do like this in reducer:

```
let product = []
product.push(action.payload)
console.log(product)
```

everytime I add new item into cart it just show the new one in an array but not the last one i added into. How can i fix this? thank you

Here is my github project if you want to look at my code:
https://github.com/nathannewyen/the-beuter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store all Products in your cart, try to use spread operator.

For example:

```
case ADD_PRODUCT_BASKET:
        return {
            ...state,
            products: [...products, action.payload],
            loading: false,
            err: ''
        };
```

This will save your previos state with all products data and add your new item to array.

Comment: And you can simplify check are there any products stored before with this condition: 

products: state.products ? [...state.products, action.payload] : action.payload;

This will prevent errors if there aren't any data stored before.